# Are optarg values persistent across successive calls to getopt?

Tags: c, getopt

By experiment, it appears that I can can capture successive values of `optarg` while iterating `int getopt(int argc, char * const argv[], const char *optstring)` and reference them later, as in the following sample program:

```
// main.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
  int opt;
  char o;
  char* a = NULL;
  char* b = NULL;

  while ( -1 != ( opt = getopt( argc, argv, "abcd:e:" ) ) )
  {
    char o = opt & 0xFF;

    switch ( o )
    {
      case 'a':
      {
        printf( "%c (%p): [%s]\n", o, optarg, (NULL == optarg ? "" : optarg ) );
        break;
      }
      case 'b':
      {
        printf( "%c (%p): [%s]\n", o, optarg, (NULL == optarg ? "" : optarg ) );
        break;
      }
      case 'c':
      {
        printf( "%c (%p): [%s]\n", o, optarg, (NULL == optarg ? "" : optarg ) );
        break;
      }
      case 'd':
      {
        printf( "%c (%p): [%s]\n", o, optarg, (NULL == optarg ? "" : optarg ) );
        a = optarg;
        break;
      }
      case 'e':
      {
        printf( "%c (%p): [%s]\n", o, optarg, (NULL == optarg ? "" : optarg ) );
        b = optarg;
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  printf( "(%p): [%s]\n", a, (NULL == a ? "" : a ) );
  printf( "(%p): [%s]\n", b, (NULL == b ? "" : b ) );

  return 0;
}
```

Compilation & example execution:

```
> gcc -g main.c && ./a.out -dabc -e def -a
d (0x7fffe8d1d2b2): [abc]
e (0x7fffe8d1d2b9): [def]
a ((nil)): []
(0x7fffe8d1d2b2): [abc]
(0x7fffe8d1d2b9): [def]
```

**Question**: Is this valid? I.e. are successive non-NULL `optarg` values valid after successive iterations of `getopt()` and/or its final iteration (when it returns -1)? I.e. is it safe to capture successive values and reference them later (i.e. without `strdup`ing them)? I don't want to assume my experimental code is generally correct.

The man page states there is an *extern* `char* optarg` but doesn't specify whether it may be reused by successive invocations of `getopt()`.

(Since the arguments to `getopt` are `argc` and `argv`, that implies that `optarg` is set to offsets of `argv` in which case I imagine it is safe to capture its successive values, but I'd like to learn if this is a correct surmise).

Comment: getopt source can be found here: https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/posix/getopt.c.html#getopt_data

Comment: `doesn't specify whether it may be reused by successive invocations of getopt()`. It looks like the behavior is not defined then. Maybe that's why it's called [nasal demons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (undefined behavior).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [POSIX specification of `getopt`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getopt.html):

> The *getopt*() function shall return the next option character (if one is found) from *argv* that matches a character in *optstring*, if there is one that matches. If the option takes an argument, *getopt*() shall set the variable *optarg* to point to the option-argument as follows:
>
> 1. If the option was the last character in the string pointed to by an element of *argv*, then ***optarg* shall contain the next element of *argv***, and *optind* shall be incremented by 2. If the resulting value of *optind* is greater than *argc*, this indicates a missing option-argument, and *getopt*() shall return an error indication.
> 2. Otherwise, ***optarg* shall point to the string following the option character in that element of *argv***, and *optind* shall be incremented by 1.

(Emphasis mine.)

This says `optarg` always points into an element of `argv`. It never makes a copy.

Since the elements of `argv` are valid for as long as your program runs, your code is valid (no copying required).

---

NB. The POSIX page also shows an [example of command line options with arguments](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getopt.html#tag_16_206_06_01) that is essentially equivalent to your version:

```
char *ifile;
...
while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, ":abf:o:")) != -1) {
    switch(c) {
    ...
    case 'f':
        ifile = optarg;
        break;
    ...
```

Comment: I'm still often unclear where POSIX fits into the picture. If I include `<unistd.h>` and invoke `getopt` as in my example code, am I getting a "POSIX-compliant" implementation of `getopt`? If not, can a user opt to get POSIX-compliant behavior by defining certain macros, etc.?

Comment: @StoneThrow POSIX is an attempt to standardize the tools, functions, APIs etc. that all the various unix-ish OSes have come up with. In this case it's hard to imagine an implementation that behaves differently wrt the lifetime of `otparg` because it's so trivial to write (a basic `getopt` implementation is like 10-15 lines of code). That said, the details depend on your OS/libc (but any OS that does something weird with `optarg` will also break tons of existing programs).

Answer (score 0):

The man page for getopt states:

> optstring is a string containing the legitimate option characters.   If
>          such  a  character is followed by a colon, the option requires an argu‐
>          ment, so getopt() places a pointer to the following text  in  the  same
>          argv-element,  or  the  text  of the following argv-element, in optarg

And also:

> By default, getopt() permutes the contents of argv as it scans, so that
>          eventually all the nonoptions are at the end.

This means, it does not allocate any memory and does not store text in static buffers, but instead works directly on the `argv` pointer array you provided and just gives you the address within it.

You can verify this behavior in code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    int opt, cur;

    while (-1 != (opt = getopt(argc, argv, "a:b:c:"))) {
        cur = optind - 1;
        printf("current elemnt = %d argv[%d] = %p optarg = %p delta = %d\n",
            cur, cur, argv[cur], optarg, (int)(optarg - argv[cur]));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That looks like a quote from a Linux man page, i.e. the glibc version of `getopt`.